# How to hide/disable/remove custom meta-box from particular posts in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am creating a WordPress plugin and I have a custom meta-box. I need to remove custom meta-box from a list of posts checked by admin. I am getting list of all posts in the plugin settings page like this:

```
<?php 
global $post;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1 );

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
        <input type="checkbox" id="postcb" name="postcb[]" value="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        <label id='postcbid' for='postcb'>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </label>
        <br>
<?php endforeach; 

wp_reset_postdata();?>
<?php echo '<input type="button" id="btnenable" name="Enable" value="Enable" onclick="displayenable()">' ?>
```

I have displayenable() function in Javascript that checks which checkboxes are checked or not, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayenable()
{
    var chk_arr =  document.getElementsByName("postcb[]");
    var chklength = chk_arr.length;             
    var cnt=0;
    for(k=0;k< chklength;k++)
    {
        if(chk_arr[k].checked===true)
        {
            cnt++;

            <?php 
            function remove_custom_metabox(){
                remove_meta_box( 'my-meta-box-id' , 'page' , 'normal' ); 
            }
            add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'remove_custom_metabox'); ?>
        }
    }
    //alert(cnt);
}
</script>
```

Now how do I remove meta box from all the posts that checked in the checkbox? 
Thanks!

EDIT 1: Since we cannot execute PHP inside JS like I was doing, I tried doing it all in PHP like this:

```
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit_btn']))
{       
    $cbarray=$_POST['postcheck'];
    if($cbarray!=NULL)
    {
        foreach($cbarray as $val)
        {
            //echo $val . '</br>';
            function remove_custom_metabox($post_type)
            {
                remove_meta_box('my-meta-box-id', $post_type, 'normal');
            }
            add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'remove_custom_metabox',99,1);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Now how do I modify this code so that I can remove meta-box from only some posts?

Comment: You can't run PHP code inside a JS block like you're trying to do...

Comment: Okay, then is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to?

Comment: I've edited my question, can you please take a look at it?

Comment: I think using JS is not necessary, did you try to [save these values](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) on the database? So it'd be `$cbarray = get_option('postcheck')`

Comment: Hey, I understand JS is not the way, so I'm doing it another way, but I'm stuck, can you check out this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52218102/how-to-remove-custom-meta-box-on-click-of-a-button