# How to remove custom meta box on click of a button?

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

I'm trying to remove a custom metabox that I've created for my plugin using PHP code. It should be removed from all the posts on click of a button.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit_btn']))
{   
    function remove_custom_metabox()
    {
        remove_meta_box( 'my-meta-box-id' , 'post' , 'normal' );
    }
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'remove_custom_metabox');
}
?>
```

Why is it not working? And is there any way to do this for multi-post custom meta-box as well? Thanks!

EDIT 1: Just to get more clear idea of what I'm doing, here is how I'm creating the custom meta-box in the main plugin file:

```
function cd_meta_box_add()
{
        add_meta_box(
                'my-meta-box-id', //id
                'Contributors', //title
                'cd_meta_box_cb', //callback
                'post', //post type
                'normal', //position
                'high' //priority
                );
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'cd_meta_box_add');
```

Comment: You should call your function like remove_custom_metabox() instead of 'remove_custom_metabox'

Comment: No, still not working. And I think in add_action() we can call function name like I did.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation you should use the admin_menu hook

Answer (score 0):

To remove custom meta box use action hook `admin_menu` or `do_meta_boxes`

```
/**
 * Remove Custom Fields meta box
 */
function wpdocs_remove_post_custom_fields() {
    remove_meta_box( 'postcustom' , 'post' , 'normal' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'wpdocs_remove_post_custom_fields' );
add_action( 'do_meta_boxes', 'wpdocs_remove_post_custom_fields' );
```

For more help see this link : [click here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box)

Comment: it's not working, I've added more information to my question can you please check it out?

Comment: first check its removing without click on button, please remove your button condition, after that add your button conditions.

Comment: I tried that as well, but it's not working. If I just add the remove_meta_box code to the main plugin file where I'm creating the custom meta-box, then it works. But how do I make it work in here?